# How in Angular 15 to redirect localhost:4200 to localhost:4200/{baseUrl}

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server, angular15

App is hosted on /test.
In previous versions I used

ng serve --base-href test

That seems to be gone now in Angular 15. So now I set in angular.json
projects -> {projectName} -> architect -> build -> options -> baseHref
Value to test.

Now app responds at:
localhost:4200/test - great

Is there an extra setting that would make
http://localhost:4200
redirect to
http://localhost:4200/test

I tried using a proxy config but it ends up in an endless redirect loop.

Comment: This would be a job of the http server you would be using to serve your applications.
Changing the base href is basically saying that the root url will be handled by something else.

Comment: It's all fine and dandy in production. It's just incredibly annoying having to manually switch fro localhost:4200 to localhost:4200/baseUrl. Surely there must be a way to achieve such a simple task.

Comment: You could have different serve , build commands, and enviroments variables in DEV and PROD. So you wouldn't need to worry about it